# Failure to handle clock inference in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

The following model in Dymola gives an error,

```
model Test1
  Real outvar;
  Real outvarc;
  Real internal;
  parameter Real Tp=0.1;
equation 
  when Clock(Tp) then
    internal = time;
  end when;
  outvar = hold(outvarc);
algorithm 
  if (firstTick(internal)) then
    outvarc := 1;
  else
    outvarc := previous(outvarc);
    outvarc := outvarc + 1;
  end if;

end Test1;
```

If I modify the variable internal as follows then the model works.

```
model Test2
  Real outvar;
  Real outvarc;
  Boolean internal(start=true);
  parameter Real Tp=0.1;
equation 
  when Clock(Tp) then
    internal = false;
  end when;
  outvar = hold(outvarc);
algorithm 
  if (firstTick(internal)) then
    outvarc := 1;
  else
    outvarc := previous(outvarc);
    outvarc := outvarc + 1;
  end if;
end Test2;
```

Is there any explanation why model Test1 is giving an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails in Dymola 2022x and earlier.
In Dymola 2023 and later it gives the warning:

> The sub clock, BaseClock_0.SubClock_1, includes pre, time, or
> non-clocked when, but no solver method is specified. This is not
> correct according to the specification and it could indicate that it
> was clocked by mistake. The warning can be disabled by setting
> Advanced.Translation.WarnForMissingSolverMethod=false;

That suggests that the simplest solution would be:

```
when Clock(Tp) then
  internal = sample(time);
end when;
```

Basically time is not a clocked variable. (Yes, I'm aware that time in clocked partitions is messier than this suggests.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion for a little more compact code of the overall model. It gives a bit different results as it uses the "discrete time" `internal` to make equations discrete/clocked automatically, but I guess the would be the use-case anyways (otherwise sampling time does not make a lot of sense).

```
model Test3
  parameter Real Tp=0.1;

  discrete Real internal;                      // "discrete" is optional in Dymola, but helps understanding
  discrete Real outvarc(start=1, fixed=true);  // setting an initial value
  Real outvar;

equation 
  internal = sample(time, Clock(Tp));    // sampling time with a locally defined clock and store it to "internal"
  outvarc = previous(outvarc)+internal;  // using a sampled/clocked variable (internal) makes the equation discrete
  outvar = hold(outvarc);                // converting to a continuous variable from a clocked one

end Test3;
```

Suggestions for further improvements welcome...