# Continuous variable used in clocked when clause is automatically discretized

Tags: modelica

```
model test
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  Real f;
  discrete Real g;
  Clock clk=Clock(0.1);
equation 
  f = sin(pi*time);
  when Clock(0.1) then
    if f >= 0 then
      g = (sin(pi*time)) - 0.1;
    else
      g = (sin(pi*time)) + 0.1;
    end if;
  end when;
end test;
```

[image]

f is assigned as a continuous function. I want to sample the value of g depended on f, but f also be changed to a discrete value. Is there anything wrong ?

Comment: btw: g must be points, not step line.

Answer (score 1):

The clock partitioning sees `f` as being used directly inside the `when Clock` and thus `f` is also seen as a *clocked* variable.

Use `sample(f)` if that is not desired:

```
model test
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;
  Real f;
  discrete Real g;
  Clock clk=Clock(0.1);
equation 
  f = sin(pi*time);
  when Clock(0.1) then
    if sample(f) >= 0 then
      g = (sin(pi*time)) - 0.1;
    else
      g = (sin(pi*time)) + 0.1;
    end if;
  end when;
end test;
```

See also: [Failure to handle clock inference in Dymola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965944/failure-to-handle-clock-inference-in-dymola)

Comment: Thank you! Is it to say, all the variables or expression inside "when-clock" block must be sampled? like:  
  when Clock(.1)  then
if sample(f >= 0) then
      g = sample(f - 0.1);
    else
      g = sample(f + 0.1);
    end if;
 end when;

Comment: They must either sampled or be on the clock, as g. If you intend to use that many expressions involving f I would introduce sampled_f=sample(f); (possibly with a shorter name) and then use that instead of repeating sample(f).